# インスタグラム API での件数指定(count)が正常に機能しない？

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

ハッシュタグからデータを取得します。
ハッシュタグに関連する画像は18件あります。
（件数指定しない場合18件返ってくるということです）

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{hash_tag}/media/recent?client_id={id}&count=12

上記で試すと正常？に動作するようで、ページングも可能となります。
12件取得、次に6件取得とできます。

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{hash_tag}/media/recent?client_id={id}&count=15

件数指定を15件に設定した場合問題があり、
この場合、全件(18件)データが返ってきます。

投稿総数の多いハッシュタグで試すと問題なさそうだったりと、
件数指定が効かないケースのパターンがわかりません。

これが明確に API のバグなら仕様がないですが、
何か他のパラメーター不足などから起きている現象でしょうか？